# rename table/feature class in filegdb using ogr or qgis

Tags: qgis, ogr, file-geodatabase

According to the [OGR SQL docs](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html#ogr_sql_alter_table), it doesn't appear that it is possible to use and ALTER statement to rename an existing table (featureclass) inside of a file geodatabase. RENAME statements can be run on columns, however. Is there a way to rename an existing table using OGR or QGIS?

This works to duplicate an existing table with the new name, and then the original table can be dropped, but it would be nice not to have to do that:

```
ogr2ogr -f 'FileGDB' -update -append -nln newtblname geodb.gdb/ geodb.gdb/
```